# Escape html with exception

Tags: python, html, escaping

I have some text that needs to be HTML-escaped, except for some `a` elements! 
How best to implement it?
Python version 2.5/2.6/2.7

Comment: Google translate didn't make the job.

Comment: You don't specify Python version. Also, give at least one example.

Comment: Sorry for my English. Python version 2.5 or 2.6, 2,7

Answer (score 2):

Your question is too vague, so I'm just guessing here.

You have some text that needs to be HTML-escaped, except for some `a` elements.

Step 1:

Do the escape. If on Python ≥ 3.2, there is the [`html`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/html.html) module and its `escape` function; otherwise, use the [`cgi`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/cgi.html) module and its `escape` function.

Step 2:

Somewhere inside your encoded text, there are zero or more parts resembling `&lt;a href="yoursite"&gt;`. Locate them (using a regular expression, perhaps) and change `&gt;` and `&lt;` back to the actual operators.

Comment: Sorry for my English again. Yes i have some text that needs to be HTML-escaped, except for some a elements!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach would probably be to encode the HTML, then decode the encoded part that matches your site. (I assume you mean encode rather than escape.)

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about Non Breaking space or `&nbsp;`  This is the tag we use to provide a white space without breaks in HTML.

Comment: Yes, i'm talking about Non Breaking space.

Comment: So why dont you use &nbsp as it is? You want it through a code or something in Python. Because the front end can be easily manipulated by this itself. :) ??